# Multiple matches with regex

Tags: regex, parsing, logging

Let's say I have a long log with something like this:

```
-----------1------------
path/to/file1
real         0.21
user         0.01
sys          0.02
  11378688  maximum resident set size
-----------2------------
path/to/file2
real         0.21
user         0.01
sys          0.02
  11378688  maximum resident set size
-----------3------------
path/to/file3
real         0.21
user         0.01
sys          0.02
  11378688  maximum resident set size
-----------4------------
path/to/file4
ERROR: Lorem ipsum error
ERROR2: Lorem ipsum error 2
real         0.59
user         0.01
sys          0.02
  11378688  maximum resident set size
```

I want to extract the path to file, error if any, time after "real" and memory used. Then transform them into format like this : "path time memory"

I've made this regex:

```
-*(?:[0-9]*)-*\n(.*)\n((?:.*\n)*)?real\s*(.*)\n.*\n.*\n\s*(.*)\s\s.*\n
```

But it only parses when there is single log entry (also parses errors if there are any), i.e. only:

```
-----------1------------
path/to/file1
real         0.21
user         0.01
sys          0.02
  11378688  maximum resident set size
```

And nothing after that.

Can someone show me the direction? I am trying it on http://www.regex101.com

Languages: c/c++, bash, java, python, go

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: If you use PHP `preg_match_all` you'll get a 2-D array with all the matches.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, didn't think you would come with web technology :) I would prefer something that I could compile fast without a lot of additional tools :)

Comment: It might be easier if you just read the file line by line (using Perl or something else) and cut out the info you need...

Comment: PHP can be used from the CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do with a perl one-liner:

```
perl -0777 -ne '@l = /-+\d+-+\n([\s\S]*?)\nreal.*?([\d.]+)\n[\s\S]+?(\d+)\s+maximum.*(\n)/g;print "@l";'  in1.txt
```

**Output:**

```
path/to/file1 0.21 11378688 
 path/to/file2 0.21 11378688 
 path/to/file3 0.21 11378688 
 path/to/file4
ERROR: Lorem ipsum error
ERROR2: Lorem ipsum error 2 0.59 11378688
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
-+(?:[0-9]*)-+\n(.*)\n((?:ERROR.*\n)*)real\s*(.*)\n.*\n.*\n\s*(.*)\s\s.*\n?
```

I replaces the `*` with `+` at the beginning because you are sure that there will be repetitions. 
Later we can explicitly check if there are any errors and capture them.

Latly I made the last `\n` optional since that broke the last group(because there is no newline at the end of the file)

Here is a link for you to see if it works for you: https://regex101.com/r/jI5yV8/1